# Args not being passed to Scipy solve_ivp

Tags: python, scipy, ode

I have copy-and-pasted the Lotka-Volterra example for Scipy's `solve_ivp` function from the documentation [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.html), but I get the error

```
lotkavolterra() missing 4 required positional arguments: 'a', 'b', 'c', and 'd'
```

It seems to me that the arguments aren't being passed to `lotkavolterra` despite it "example of a system with additional parameters". The code is below.

```
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp

def lotkavolterra(t, z, a, b, c, d):
    x, y = z
    return [a*x - b*x*y, -c*y + d*x*y]

sol = solve_ivp(lotkavolterra, [0, 15], [10, 5], args=(1.5, 1, 3, 1), dense_output=True)

print(sol)
```

How do I resolve my issue?

Comment: The `args` argument was added to `solve_ivp` in SciPy 1.4.0.  Which version of SciPy are you using?  You can check with `import scipy; print(scipy.__version__)`

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Thank you. My problem was an outdated SciPy because I wasn't using a virtualenv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your version of solve_ivp doesn't provide the `args` argument, you can use a lambda function:

```
sol = solve_ivp(lambda t, z: lotkavolterra(t, z, 1.5, 1, 3, 1), [0, 15], [10, 5], dense_output=True)
```

However, it's highly recommended to update your scipy version, like Warren already hinted in the comments.